# What encryption type is this?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

This is the encrypted string,  I can see a pattern in it and have done a lot of research but I cant seem to find what I need.

OH0fRX0gOHZgOH0tOH4fRX8tOr0gOHZgOH0tOH4fOrZgOH0fRX8tOH4gOHZgOH0tOr4gRX8tOr4fRX0gOHZfOH4fRX4fOr0tOrZgOr4tObZgRX4fOr4tOrZeRX4fOrZfRX0fOH4tOH0gRX0fRX0fOrZeRX4gOH4tOr4gRX0gOr4tOH0fOrZfOH4fRX4tOr0fOH4gRX8tOr4fRX4fOHZgOr4fRX0gRX4fRX0tObZgRX4fOr4tOrZeRX4fOH4tOr0fOrZfOHZgOH4tObZgOr4fRX4tOr0fOrZgOH0tOr0gRX8tOHZgOH0tObZgOr0fRX4gOr4tOr0tOr4tOH0tObZgOr0gRX0gOHZfOr0tOr0fRX8tOr0gOrZgOH0tOr4tOH4tOHZfOr4tOr0fOH4gRX4gOr0fOrZfOH4gOr4tOr4gOrZfOH4fRX4gRX0gOrZgOH0fOr4tObZgOrZgOr0fRX4gOr4tOH4fOr4gRX0fOH4tOr0fRX4gOH0tOr4gOrZgOr4fOr0tOH0gOr4tOH0gOH0tOr4fOH0tOH0gOr4tOr0fOH4fRX4gOr0fOrZfOr0fRX4gOr4tOr0tOH0fRX4fOr0gRX4gOr0fOrZgOr4fOr0tOH4fOr4gRX0fOr4fOHZgOr4fOr0tOH4fOr4gRX4gOr0fOrZgRX4gOHZgOr4tOr4fRX0fOH0tOr4tOH4fOrZfOr4gOHZgOr4fRX4fOr0gRX4gOH0tOr0gOrZfOrZfOr4tOH4fOrZgOH4fRX0fOr4tOr4fOH0tOr4gRX0gOrZgOr0fRX4fOH0gRX0gOH0fRX0gOr0tOH4fRX0

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Nope, I already tried that.

Comment: Great! Then you should tell us what you have and haven't tried.

Comment: I have tried base64 and all of the types on this page:

Comment: http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: Without more context this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I realize this now that I look back at it.  I just don't know where else to turn for help.

Comment: It still looks like base64 to me. Not just the alphabet, but the fact that there are obvious 4 character groupings that repeat numerous times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the text is encrypted with the NULL encryption algorithm described in [RFC 2410](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2410).  If I run it through the accompanying decryption algorithm, it decrypts properly without error and gives the following plain text:

```
OH0fRX0gOHZgOH0tOH4fRX8tOr0gOHZgOH0tOH4fOrZgOH0fRX8tOH4gOHZgOH0tOr4gRX8tOr4fRX0gOHZfOH4fRX4fOr0tOrZgOr4tObZgRX4fOr4tOrZeRX4fOrZfRX0fOH4tOH0gRX0fRX0fOrZeRX4gOH4tOr4gRX0gOr4tOH0fOrZfOH4fRX4tOr0fOH4gRX8tOr4fRX4fOHZgOr4fRX0gRX4fRX0tObZgRX4fOr4tOrZeRX4fOH4tOr0fOrZfOHZgOH4tObZgOr4fRX4tOr0fOrZgOH0tOr0gRX8tOHZgOH0tObZgOr0fRX4gOr4tOr0tOr4tOH0tObZgOr0gRX0gOHZfOr0tOr0fRX8tOr0gOrZgOH0tOr4tOH4tOHZfOr4tOr0fOH4gRX4gOr0fOrZfOH4gOr4tOr4gOrZfOH4fRX4gRX0gOrZgOH0fOr4tObZgOrZgOr0fRX4gOr4tOH4fOr4gRX0fOH4tOr0fRX4gOH0tOr4gOrZgOr4fOr0tOH0gOr4tOH0gOH0tOr4fOH0tOH0gOr4tOr0fOH4fRX4gOr0fOrZfOr0fRX4gOr4tOr0tOH0fRX4fOr0gRX4gOr0fOrZgOr4fOr0tOH4fOr4gRX0fOr4fOHZgOr4fOr0tOH4fOr4gRX4gOr0fOrZgRX4gOHZgOr4tOr4fRX0fOH0tOr4tOH4fOrZfOr4gOHZgOr4fRX4fOr0gRX4gOH0tOr0gOrZfOrZfOr4tOH4fOrZgOH4fRX0fOr4tOr4fOH0tOr4gRX0gOrZgOr0fRX4fOH0gRX0gOH0fRX0gOr0tOH4fRX0
```

The plain text does not make much sense to me, however.  But that's the fundamental problem with data: There is no data to represent “no data”.  Therefore, without any context information that restricts the set of valid strings to a true subset of all possible strings, we cannot possibly tell whether any sequence of characters is “data” or “garbage”.  Only if we know what to expect, we can tell whether a given string matches that expectation or not.

Check out the Wikipedia article on [Coding Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory) for more information.

Comment: Hehe, but you're just going to confuse him.

Comment: @GregS Do you think I was unfair?  I thought the problem would be explained best by some humor.  I have edited my post to add the name of the algorithm to hopefully make it clearer.  Though I really recommend reading that RFC, too.

Comment: This is one of the more complex algorithms I've seen.

Comment: I really thought that full 52-round ROT13 was the most complex, before I saw this monster.